# How to Supply Language Parameter to PowerForm

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

How can I supply the language parameter to PowerForm URL?

The way(locale=fr) mentioned below does not work. Please help me to set up the Docusign form Multilingual as per customers language.

https://powerforms-d.docusign.net/1cff88ec-2c74-44f7-XXXX-f8cb025d64b3?env=demo&acct=XXXXXX-9143-438e-8c68-4bd3fa6a6e18&Investor_Email=sXXXpe.XXX&locale=fr

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work with "recipientLang=fr".

The DocuSign PowerForm app was refreshed recently and it appears the team used a different query param. I can request an update to the accepted query params, documentation, or both.

Comment: Supported language codes (as of 2021/11/11):
  'ar',
  'bg',
  'cs',
  'da',
  'de',
  'el',
  'en',
  'en-gb',
  'en_GB',
  'es',
  'es-mx',
  'es_MX',
  'et',
  'fa',
  'fi',
  'fr',
  'fr-ca',
  'fr_CA',
  'he',
  'hi',
  'hr',
  'hu',
  'hy',
  'id',
  'it',
  'ja',
  'ko',
  'lt',
  'lv',
  'ms',
  'no',
  'nl',
  'pl',
  'pt',
  'pt-br',
  'pt_BR',
  'ro',
  'ru',
  'sk',
  'sl',
  'sr',
  'sv',
  'th',
  'tr',
  'uk',
  'vi',
  'zh',
  'zh-cn',
  'zh_CN',
  'zh-tw',
  'zh_TW'

Comment: I have tried this way, but does not work

Comment: "recipientLang=fr" looks like for Email translation. What about UI, Where user redirected for sign?

Comment: Maybe I am missing some details in your question. Using the URL you posted in the original question, I see French when I change the "locale" query param to "recipientLang": https://powerforms-d.docusign.net/1cff88ec-2c74-44f7-XXXX-f8cb025d64b3?env=demo&acct=XXXXXX-9143-438e-8c68-4bd3fa6a6e18&Investor_Email=sXXXpe.XXX&recipientLang=fr

Comment: I have tried a lot but still does not work. As per DocuSign support, It's not possible. Customers can choose the language from the bottom of the page.

Comment: That is correct. Users can change their language using the language selector in the footer in the powerform session and in the signing session. For the powerform session, you can use the "recipientLang" query parameter in the URL to preselect a language.

Comment: That's not possible, I've tried a lot. seems like, DocuSign discontinue that feature.